# I love git but it's too heavy for my colleagues.. which DVCs has the lowest barrier of entry?

Tags: git, excel, version-control, mercurial

**TL;DR: I'm looking for a DVCS with a much simpler (and less dangerous) command set than Git, which rocks on Windows and MacOS X.**

To give you some background:

I've been the only one testing Git for Revision Control at my company for about 6 months.

I realized today that Git is actually WAY too heavy for my colleagues when I had to spent a good chunk of the day restoring a corrupted repository.

I'm a .NET and Rails developer and I really like UNIX!

The rest of my colleges are data bods and Excel developers (make fun all you like but they do some SERIOUSLY hard-core stuff with data in Excel VBA and T-SQL).

On the other hand, they can't stand unix and barf at the idea of using the command line for anything except nostalgia.

While I know there are some great Git GUIs now and the CLI has seen some massive improvements, Git is still a massive difference in workflow for them as they use currently dropbox to collaborate on worksheet code etc..

At the moment the only option seems to be Mercurial.

Is this close enough to what we need or is there something simpler (a great GUI would be nice too)?

By the way: Open Source isn't necessary and we're open to spending some money.

---

After much thinking I've decided to leave things for now. I really enjoy Git myself but some people just can't get on board with revision control.

So I'll continue to force Git on the web team but leave the data nerds be!

Comment: How exactly did you manage to corrupt a repo? Did you manually touch anything in the .git directory? I can understand thinking git's too heavy for many other reasons, but not that - it's been quite stable for me.

Comment: Also, I don't know exactly what you're going to be versioning here, but aren't you going to run into some problems with Excel VBA being stuck inside of the binary worksheet files?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure really.. I went to make a commit one day using the gui and got a dialog saying that it "failed to write trees", a hash of the commit and a filename.. then a windows notification in the system tray saying that git.exe had corrupted a file.. then i tried to make a commit using the command line and got the same error.. so i checked out an older branch and tried to make a commit on that branch and got the same error.. googled around for a bit.. the problem was i had a really urgent deadline so i couldn't really tell my boss to wait while i futz the repo back to life..

Comment: Oh and yeah.. i'm still looking for a dvcs that can version excel spreadsheets as they are seen as just BLOB's.. Locking would be the only way around that but that doesn't really work in a non-centralized situation..

Comment: Hi Daniel, glad to read you're trying Plastic... if you like the current version, you'll love what we're coming up with in 4.0, first thing is git's interop, and fast-export/import support too :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't give up on git. Train and support and they will like it. I was in the same boat and we came out ahead in the end. Well worth the effort.

Gitk and git gui are great if they are command line adverse.

You are heading down a path of a graphic studio not using Photoshop because it's "too hard to learn" - so they go with MS Paint. Don't do that.

UPDATE:

With the use of git attributes, you can store the excel files as uncompressed xml. You can now do diffs between them. Not sure how useful that would be. It depends of how much of the excel sheets you are changing and how.

Hope this helps.

Comment: :D loving the photoshop idea! as much as i enjoy git i've been playing with Plastic SCM recently and have to say its a very nice alternative!  Hmmm.. decisions decisions!

Comment: :P i'd forgotten about this thread.. will post an update on what we actually did..

Answer (score 18):

Mercurial is simple DVCS and a powerful one to extend.

- https://www.mercurial-scm.org
- Joel Spolsky's tutorial: http://hginit.com/

Subversion being older has more UI tools but DVCS are not far behind.

You could use a UI : [TortoiseHg](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) which can be used on windows and there is http://jasonfharris.com/machg/ which is rocking UI for Mac.

Answer (score 6):

Repos can corrupt in any VCS.  The interesting difference with git is that the errors are more often recoverable beyond just a simple restore from a backup, although as you've discovered it can take some real voodoo.  That doesn't preclude the lighter restore from backup option, though.

Personally, I think bazaar is the easiest DVCS for a beginner to learn on their own.  They have great documentation and a newbie-friendly community.  It's what I started out on.  However, with as much git experience as you have, I think you would find bazaar limiting.  Mercurial is much more on par with git feature and power-wise, and has a less unixy command line, but you're going to be avoiding the CLI anyway.

I would recommend putting them on [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/).  The workflow is going to be a change for them no matter what, and there are things you can do to make it easier for them.  Remember they will be getting training and support from you, which is going to be much more newbie-friendly to them than the git man pages or whatever you've been using.

I would recommend starting them out without any branching, just pull, commit, and push from master to origin.  This is just about as easy with TortoiseGit as with any other VCS.  Create a different local folder with a different repository if they *need* to work on more than one branch at once, which is about as close to dropbox sharing as you can get.  Then you can introduce more advanced concepts as they start to demand them.

Answer (score 5):

Mercurial/[TortoiseHg](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) and [Bazaar](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/)/[TortoiseBzr](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/TortoiseBzr) are the DVCS I could think of other than Git thats opensource.

Comment: Just seen the difference between a Hg and Git clone on Google Fonts: it's huge! Git I believe less than a minute, Hg seems to go to several hours... If someone uses this question to choose a DVCS, this is why Git is essential. And nowadays the initial cons are not relevant any more: there is very good Windows support nowadays and the interface is a lot better than it was.

Answer (score 4):

You might look at http://www.infoq.com/articles/dvcs-guide which documents the differences between the 3 most popular DVCSes.  It has sections on ease-of-use and lets you compare that against features.

Comment: That comparison is unfortunately very outdated (the third-party forest extension is no longer to be used, use built-in subrepositories instead) and wrong (it says local branching is impossible and that one must use clones -- Mercurial has always supported multiple branches per repository).

Answer (score 4):

As you mention that the main kind of format they use are excel spreadsheet, the usage of a DVCS compare to their current dropbox solution seems less obvious than it might sound.

Excel spreadsheet are considered by most of the (D)VCS as binary files, even the .XLSX format (which is basically a set of XML files zipped). So the VCS won't really be able to do a comparison between versions and even less to perform a merge. Knowing that, Dropbox is not that bad as it allows them to benefit automatically from a backup of the 30 last days of revision, and even a so called "pack-rat" solution to go more back in time.

So, with that in mind, I would rather not recommend a DVCS as it could increase the merge problem if the workflow is not carefully followed and go in favor of something like SVN, which has a "lock" command to prevent other users to commit erroneously on such files.

For the GUI part, I would recommend [Version](http://versionsapp.com/) for the Mac and [Vercue](http://vercue.com/) for Windows (or course, there is always the TortoiseSVN option).

Comment: Yup totally agree with you.. locking would probably be the only solution.. i just dont like centralized vcs, its a major pain.. dropbox may have to do for the xls files but the .sql file can be versioned as they are text files... maybe its time to write a git-excel bridge.. wonder if anyone else has this problem?

Comment: Well, having THEM working on a centralized VCS should not be an obstacle for YOU to work on a decentralized one. Both hgsubversion and git-svn are excellent bridges to work with, respectively, Mercurial and Git over subversion. Letting you having nearly all the power of a DVCS, while still, at the end, pushing your changes to a central repository.

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a good idea.. i'm still really tempted by Plastic SCM (see my edit on the original question) cause it's basically a client-server type thing.. except you can run a local server and use it as a DVCS.. this would be perfect.. i guess the only thing is that git and svn are already quite well adopted.. hmmmmmm what to do?!